# Package Manager Console search on Id only

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2012, nuget

If I enter this command...

Get-Package -ListAvailable -Filter newtonsoft

I get a listing of all packages that reference the string 'newtonsoft' in their Id or Description/Release Notes fields.  Is there a way to search the Id field only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Where-Object` cmdlet to filter the results.  The `$_` represents the current object in the pipeline:

```
Get-Package -ListAvailable -Filter newtonsoft | Where {$_.<prop-name> -match '<regex>'}
```

Note that the `-match` operator matches the value of the specified property name to the specified regular expression.  Specifically  I think you want this:

```
Get-Package -ListAvailable -Filter newtonsoft | Where {$_.Id -match 'newtonsoft'}
```